# c# WebRequest only works with proxy

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make a POST request to an API and it eventually times out. If I run it through a proxy it works as intended so I have no idea how to figure out where to go.

```
string url = "https://" + this.Host + ":1234" + uri;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
//request.Proxy = new WebProxy ("127.0.0.1", 8080);

request.ContentType = "application/json";

string response = string.Empty;
try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        response = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using any other app like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to check the URL from the same computer?

Comment: @VincentP I am not developing the API and I can make calls in a regular browser to the API from the same computer.

Comment: This has to do with CORS. You cannot make calls to an api outside it's domain if the api is not using Cross Origin Resource Sharing or JSONP.

Comment: @allencage if its CORS how come the API calls work when running through a proxy or manually doing them in a browser?